# Check if csv file is empty in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have-

```
data=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
if data.empty==False:
    do something
```

In my code the dataframe data generated sometimes is empty depending on some conditions. Now when the csv file is empty its throwing error-

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

what should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: can you define empty, does it have headers?

Comment: @Datanovice no it doesnt

Answer (score 5):

You can use `try-except` construction:

```
import pandas as pd

try:
    data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
    print('Empty csv file!')
```